# Why have a var inner function in javascript function

Tags: javascript

I am picking up maintenance on some javascript code implemented by a guy who was suppposed to be somewhat of a javascript guru and he uses the following construction a lot:

```
someComplicatedFoo : function(arg){
    var transformedArg = this.operationOnArg(arg)
    //some logic here

    var someBarFunction = function(internalArg){
          //some complex logic with internalArg
          return somethingNew
    }

    //other logic
    var somethingNew = someBarFunction(transformedArg)
    //yet more logic that operates on somethingNew

    return somethingNew

}
```

What is the point of the internal function construction? Why not just inline the logic where the logic needs to be called? I understand the modularity but I am inclined to think that just having the logic inline would be more readable.

I am not asking about the usage of the term var. I am pretty sure I understand what exactly is going on I just don't understand why you wouldn't inline the logic or break up into multiple discrete functions.

I am mostly a java developer these days who does javascript when the situation requires.

I am specifically looking for a performance benefit or functional gain so I know whether or not to use the practice in my own code.

Comment: If you want to reuse a certain bit of logic inside of a function and not make that logic available outside of the function...

Comment: @Pamblam Yeah I thought of that but the previous developer is only using it once

Comment: If they're only using it once then there's no reason to do that. In fact, it's a waste of memory. Some people would argue it makes it more readable but I'd disagree.

Comment: Might have been using it only once, but what if it was needed again in a future update?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol fair point but doesn't make sense in context nor with how often he does it

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol and what if it's not needed at all in the future? Or if it is needed, but not exactly like that? Why waste energy today for something you *might* need someday?? YAGNI!

Comment: @inquisitiveIdiot: Have you never had a private method in a class in java? It's *kind of* like that. Even if it's only used once it does help to break up the code into distinct pieces with distinct functions. If, for example, you needed to not call `someBarFunction` in debugging, you'd only need to comment out the line that call it rather than commenting out a huge block

Comment: @MattBurland That's a reasonable explanation I could buy that. Would it be expected to remove in production code or no?

Comment: If this is not ES6 code (which has block scoping) then it uses function scoping, so he may have chosen to use the inner function to prevent his inner variables from interfering with those in the outer function.

Comment: @ close voters Why do you think this is off topic? It is a question about why I would do something in javascript and may have a legitimate answer

Comment: @Amit: Why waste energy trying to figure out what some block of code inside another larger block of code does when you can just encapsulate it in a function so it's clear and self-contained? You'll spend more time maintaining code that you spent writing it.

Comment: @inquisitiveIdiot nobody has voted to close it for being off-topic, the votes are due to the question being too broad. There is no specific answer, unless you can get your previous developer to come on here and give you a definitive explanation :)

Comment: *Would it be expected to remove in production code or no?*, No. Unless there is an actual demonstrable performance problem which is unlikely.  *Why do you think this is off topic?* You are asking people to read the mind of some random developer. There are lots of possible answers. It's too broad.

Comment: These are all excuses for code smell. The problem starts with `someComplicatedFoo`. It's **too complicated**. *That's* the problem, *that's* what's causing such entangled code to be written in the first place, and *that's* what needs to be refactored.

Comment: @MattBurland if that's the excuse, the encapsulated function needs to be placed outside the main flow of the "public" function, not in the middle. And anyway, the function is too complicated.

Comment: @MattBurland fair but I thought there could have been a legitimate fact answer and you have proposed several. Those are all I think reasonable answers to this question

Comment: *Those are all I think reasonable answers to this question* which is the very definition of "too broad". There are many answers. There are plenty of reasons why you *might* do this, but only your enigmatic "javascript guru" knows why *they* did it.

Comment: Module pattern for scoping your object methods and properties. Protects against naming clashes - especially when more than one developer is working on the project at a time. There is nothing wrong with the pattern in general, but using it does make the code a bit more difficult to follow if you dont know what you are looking at and if you are the only person working on the application/site and you dont plan to distribute the code as a plugin - then only your guru knows why he/she used this pattern.

Comment: @Amit: Not true at all. If you don't want it polluting a scope any higher than where it is actually needed. I'm not saying it's always a good idea. Or if it's a good idea *here* (because we don't have enough context), but you seem to be arguing against the existence of private methods anywhere.

Comment: @MattBurland - not even close to that. I'm arguing that if a function is that complicated, it needs to be refactored to become a full blown module (class...), tucked away nicely in a dedicated source file, and have private methods outside of the main flow of the function so it doesn't distract the reader.